# Using partials independently

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dust.js

I'd trying to work out if its possible load what I believe is referred to as a partial in linkedin-dustjs without loading its parent.

For example if I have this partial (login.dust):

```
{>layout/}
{<content}
    <!-- Login Screen -->
{/content}
```

Which loads this page (layout.dust):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {+content/}
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to ouput login.dust without rendering layout.dust? The reason being that I might want to render the whole page when a user requests the login page. However if a user is on another page is tries to perform an action that requires login I might want to ajax load the login partial and add it to the existing page without requiring the layout as that would already be present.

If its not possible is there a way to 'pass' on template to another so I can render out the login template and pass it to the layout template.

I apologies if I'm not using the correct terms. Feel free to correct me as I'm not that well read on how linkedin-dustjs works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding one more template. Your `layout.dust` template would remain unchanged. Your `login.dust` template would look like:

```
{>layout/}
{<content}
    {>loginForm/}
{/content}
```

And the new `loginForm.dust` would contain your login form. Then you can include `{>loginForm/}` wherever you need to add the login form.

Comment: That solves my problem, even if I do have to create another template. Thank you.

Comment: On a side note do you know how I include dust-core on a page as when I add the script tag it doesn't load?

Comment: It depends on what you're using as your source. For instance, you could use `<script type=text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-linkedin/2.0.0/dust-core.js"></script`.

Comment: I believe the latest dust version is 2.0.3.